# How to find the degrees of freedom for a chi-square variable

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

How does one find the degrees of freedom for a Chi-square random variable when trying to fit a distribution to a sample?

I read an explanation regarding this in [this source](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/tools/stats/chisquare.html). I don't understand how to find it yet. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Do you remember _where_ you read the quoted sentence? If so, could you (i) tell us the source of your quotation and (ii) verify that the quoted sentence has been correctly transcribed into your question? Thanks.

Comment: @DilipSarwate here's the source: http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/tools/stats/chisquare.html

Comment: Re-reading that, I see that I misquoted that (as to what it means). I must have got confused after reading from several sources. I'll edit the question to remove that. apologies

Answer (score 1):

See the summary:

> 1.Divide your measurements into *categories*, which can be qualitative characteristics or ranges of numbers.

---

> 7. Degrees of freedom = number categories minus one.

---

In the example, you have three categories, which are the three soil types. so the number of degrees of freedom is 2.